# Does "es lo que es" have similar contextual meaning as is literal translation in english?

Tags: traducción

"Es lo que es" is the literal translation of the phrase "it is what it is." In English (at least American English) this phrase is used to express acceptance, usually of something negative, such as "Well this sucks, but it is what it is." Does this phrase in Spanish hold that same meaning, or is there a different phrase that sounds more natural to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a poor translation, probably, I've heard:

- Es lo que hay, que (se le) va hacer.
- Así nomás es la cosa.
- Así es como son las cosas nomás po.
- No hay na'(nada) que hacer.
- En fin, 'tamos(estamos) cagados.
- ¡Me conformo igual (a pesar de todo)!
- ¡No hay por donde!
- ¡Ya está, qué (se le) va a hacer!
- ¡Ni modo!

Answer (score 1):

Here in Argentina you would say: "Es lo que hay", but it depends on the context.

Comment: Yes, it is not "10,000 things".

Answer (score 0):

Titulo Es lo que es, hay lo que hay

Canción de Revólver
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MzEuQLkC2E

Parte de la letra

Fueron como una habitación de hotel sin pasado ni futuro,

Fueron lo que fueron porque Dios se empeñó en que fuera así.

No quedó como constancia de su encuentro

Más que el día, el año, el mes en la pared

Escrito con las uñas en el yeso de aquel viejo hotel.

Los dos sabían que los lazos del amor se hacen de espino.

Los dos sabían que quererse es condenarse hasta el final.

Los dos sabían que a menudo no es bastante un "yo te quiero".

Pero vida no hay más que una y, que yo sepa, no dan más,

Por ahora no dan más.

*Es lo que es, hay lo que hay. Por ahora no dan más*.

*Es lo que es, hay lo que hay. Por ahora no dan más*.

**Es lo que es, hay lo que hay ó (esto) es lo que hay, son expresiones que se dicen cuando nos tenemos que conformar con lo que es, lo que tenemos ó hay en ese momento ya que no queda ó no hay más remedio que aceptarlo**. Así que creo que viene a ser lo mismo en el idioma Inglés "it is what it is".